# run a function in react render method jsx template string

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a simple function to capitalize the first letter of timer_type,
the func is `const capitalize = (string) => { return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1) }`
In the render method of my app I have a long template string, the in the timerTypes.find method when there is a timer by type, I need the first letter to be uppercase. So need to invoke the capitalize. how would you invoke a function inline of a jsx?

```
<Box
    sx={{
        marginBlock: 3,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
    }}
    >
    {timerHistory &&
        timerHistory.map((history, index) => (
            <Box key={index}>
                 <strong>
                 {`${
                     timerTypes.find(
                         (type) => type.id === history.timer_type
                     )?.timer_type.capitalize
                 } for ${toTime(history.duration_seconds)}`}
                 </strong>
                 {` on a ${Math.round(
                     history.goal_seconds / 60
                 )} minute timer ${age(history.created_at)}`}
           </Box>
       ))}
</Box>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking how to call a function, which clearly would be something like: `capitalize(some_value)`  The code shown calls several functions already, there's structurally no difference.  Can you clarify specifically what isn't working as expected in the code shown?

Comment: Thanks @David but that is not it, I have tried `?.timer_type(capitalize())}` the err I am getting is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')`

Comment: @Fighithebird would you mind explaining why Davids suggestion `capitalize(some_value)` is not it? That's how you call a function with a value in JS. There seems to be some unspoken requirement or expectation. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Thomas David's solution works I applied it in the wrong part of my code.

Answer (score 2):

To invoke the capitalize function inline of a JSX, you can use the curly braces {} to enclose the function.

```
{capitalize("A test string")} //should work.
```

Read more about it here:
https://react.dev/learn/javascript-in-jsx-with-curly-braces

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is simply... How to call a function in JavaScript.

Take a look at what you have here:

```
timerTypes.find(
    (type) => type.id === history.timer_type
)?.timer_type.capitalize
```

All you're doing is simply appending the name of the function to a value somewhere.  But your function isn't defined as being a part of any given class or type (as opposed to the `find` function also used on this line of code, which *is* defined on the `Array` type).  And *even if it was*, you're still not *invoking* that function (as you already do with the `find` function here).

Your function is just a plain function.  It is invoked directly and passed a value.  So you would invoke it directly, and pass it a value:

```
capitalize(timerTypes.find(
    (type) => type.id === history.timer_type
)?.timer_type)
```

For more practice and information on how to define and use functions in JavaScript, you are *highly encouraged* to start with some introductory tutorials on the JavaScript language.  Building a React application is a *fairly advanced* topic as an introduction to the basic syntax and structure of the language itself.